# Issue with ping and opkg update on Beaglebone black

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I'm new with BeagleBone Black, i'm using Angstrom default distro, often i have trouble with ping,opkg update and ssh.

BeagleBone Black has 2 Network Interface, the virtual one (On USB) and the phisical eth0.

I can connect with SSH only with the USB ip, in the other i obtain:

Write failed: Broken pipe

And I've seen a lot of problems during ping and during opkg update.

OPKG stay sometimes undefinitly on this screen:
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2012.12/ipk/eglibc/armv7a-vfp-neon/base/Packages.gz.

With no results.

And Ping often can't resolve ping to google.it

Someone had similar issues?
Thanks

Comment: `ping` and `opkg` will have problems if you haven't set the time on the bone. Are you running `/usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u pool.ntp.org`?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/Kyq1NQOFSns) might prove helpful in fixing the opkg update problem. Most of the people in that thread do some variation of the following:

1. Boot your BBB and log in via SSH.
2. Edit /etc/resolv.conf to add Google's public DNS server:

   ```
   # cat "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   # route add default gw 192.168.7.1
   ```
4. Run opkg update and upgrade:

   ```
   # opkg update
   # opkg upgrade
   ```

Keep in mind, that your changes to the /etc/resolv.conf file will be lost at reboot. I have yet to investigate why.

Comment: hi i was facing the same issue, followed the above steps. after opkg update i am getting following output on the terminal  Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/omap/packages/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/barrier_breaker. but barrier_breaker file is empty.